# Vehicle Detection using CNN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

Working on a vehicle detection project. Basically I have two sensors; Radar and Camera. I would be figuring the Region of Interest in the camera image data through Radar features, and try examining if that region contains a vehicle through ML prediction. Planning to train my model from the available resources online like:

-https://cogcomp.seas.upenn.edu/Data/Car/

-http://ai.stanford.edu/~jkrause/cars/car_dataset.html

I was reviewing a few papers, and some stackex feeds. All of them majorly supports CNN as the approach to opt for.

My query is: -The training dataset images are of 64,64 dimension with two labels(Vehicle and Non-Vehicle) (Example- [Non-Vehicle Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Quh9B.png) [Vehicle Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ5NP.png)). Although my input image could be any scaled image such as( [Region predicted to be Car from Radar Sensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPEF6.png)) can we model a DNN to take to predict the exact region of the car from that image?

Apologies if the logic of the question is bad, I'm completely new to DL AND ML.

Comment: You could instead train an object detection model ( such as YOLO ) for detecting the position of cars. It will return the confidence score whether the car is present or not. See [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-a-custom-object-detection-model-with-yolo-v5-917e9ce13208).

Comment: I did follow your feedback @ShubhamPanchal I sent 4 ROIs from a 1600x900 image, each of 200x200 dimensions; The model gave results back in 3.8 secs, whereas if I feed in the original 1600x900, it gave result in 1.01secs. Is this the expected behavior in Yolo v3? Shouldn't the former be faster? Also, anything less than 200x200, Yolo isn't working correctly( It is detecting persons, but not cars and trucks)